# Using row values to decide what columns to multiply in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that has 0's and 1's.
I would like to use it to decide what values are added in another dataframe df2 and print the highest value across all of the Diseases.

df1

```
       Gene1    Gene2    Gene3   Gene4
    S1  1   0   1   0
    S2  1   0   1   1
    S3  1   1   0   0
    S4  1   0   1   0
    S5  0   1   1   1
    S6  0   0   1   0
    S7  0   1   0   0
    S8  0   0   1   0
```

df2

```
  Disease  Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
      D1    0.1      1     26      1
      D2      1      1      1      1
      D3      1     18    0.5     17
      D4     25      1      1      1
      D5      1      1      1      1
      D6      1     33      1     12
      D7      1    0.3      1      1
      D8      5      1      1      1
```

thus for S1 of df1
the result is

```
  Disease  Result  
      D1    2.6 
      D2      1 
      D3    0.5   
      D4     25   
      D5      1 
      D6      1  
      D7      1
      D8      5
```

then print the highest value and Disease.
Thus

```
D4 25
```

It would be an added bonus if i could store the results for each top value in a separate dataframe. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: this is because i messed up the question. This one makes the problem clearer. I am not certain how to remove questions. Can you help me with this also...Sorry

Comment: There will be a delete button beneath your question I think

Comment: I'm not at all clear how you obtained your results for Sa of df1.  For example, S1 indicators are 1, 0, 1, 0 and df2 D1 indicators are are 0.1, 1, 26, 1.  Wouldn't the result for S1/D1 be max(1*.1, 0*1, 1*26, 0*1) = 26.  Similarly, is S1/D3 max(1*1, 0*18, 1*0.5, 0*17) = 1.0.  These are both different from your desired output, so I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: Hi Alexander. The aim was to look where there are 1 for S1 under each gene category. Then use only the values from df2 that match for some operation addition or multiplication(I prefer addition). Thus if S1 is the reference(1,0,1,0) then for df2 only values from Gene1 and Gene3 columns would be considered. If we multiply these two columns for D1 of df2 then we get0.1*26 =2.6. If we add the two columns we get 26.1. I hope this is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what is your index and what isn't but if the indices match then you can use a boolean mask and then call `max` and pass `axis=1`:

```
In [55]:
df.index = df1.index
df1[df==1].max(axis=1)

Out[55]:
Disease
D1    26.0
D2     1.0
D3    18.0
D4    25.0
D5     1.0
D6     1.0
D7     0.3
D8     1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [170]: df3 = df2[[x for x in df2.columns if 'Gene' in x]]

In [171]: df3
Out[171]: 
   Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
0    0.1    1.0   26.0      1
1    1.0    1.0    1.0      1
2    1.0   18.0    0.5     17
3   25.0    1.0    1.0      1
4    1.0    1.0    1.0      1
5    1.0   33.0    1.0     12
6    1.0    0.3    1.0      1
7    5.0    1.0    1.0      1

In [172]: pd.concat([df2['Disease'], df3.where(df1.reset_index(drop=True) == 1, 1).product(axis=1)], axis=1)
Out[172]: 
    0     1
0  D1   2.6
1  D2   1.0
2  D3  18.0
3  D4  25.0
4  D5   1.0
5  D6   1.0
6  D7   0.3
7  D8   1.0
```